# Floor attached to player

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I am working in Unity and have a floor attached to the x,z coordinates of the player, so I do not need to load the floor in tiles. The floor is always leveled.

However I notice that when the player (or any other object) is on the floor and moving, the speed is increased because the floor is actually moving as well.

My floor is a kinematic rigidbody and has no physics material applied.

Answer (score 0):

I set the physicsmaterial for the plane to have no friction and the character to have no platform which seems to work.